# I want to run a task for al files and exclude those who did not change

Tags: msbuild

I have two buildtargets to check my code quality.

I run the following buildtargets every time i compile. This takes up too much time and i would like them to only check the files that did change.

In other words i want to filter files that did not change from the `ItemGroup` `CppCheckFiles` / `LinterFiles`.

```
  <Target Name="CppCheck">
    <ItemGroup>
      <CppCheckFiles Include="*main.c" />
      <CppCheckFiles Include="Source/*/*.c" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="$(Configuration) starting." Importance="High" />
    <Exec Command="C:\Cppcheck\cppcheck.exe %(CppCheckFiles.FullPath)  --enable=style --template=&quot;{file}({line}): error:{severity}-{id}: {message}&quot;" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="SPLint">
    <ItemGroup>
      <LinterFiles Include="*main.c" />
      <LinterFiles Include="Source/*/*.c" />
      <LinterFiles Include="Source/*/*.h" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="$(Configuration) starting." Importance="High" />
    <Exec Command="splintCaller %(LinterFiles.FullPath)" />
  </Target>
```

I know that the regular build process does this and i wonder if i have to go so fas as to write my own task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is [incremental Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171483.aspx). Where MSBuild compares Timestamps to exclude complete Buildtargets if nothing changed.

The following target creates a timesstamp for each file and skippes those files that did not change.

cppcheck.exe returns -1 if an error was detected and the timestamp is not written.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="CppCheck" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <ItemGroup>
      <CppCheckFiles Include="*main.c" />
      <CppCheckFiles Include="Source/*/*.c" />
    </ItemGroup>   

  <Target Name="CppCheck"
    Inputs="@(CppCheckFiles)" 
    Outputs="CCPCheck\%(CppCheckFiles.Filename)%(CppCheckFiles.Extension).stamp">
    <Exec Command="C:\Cppcheck\cppcheck.exe %(CppCheckFiles.FullPath)  --enable=style --template=&quot;{file}({line}): error:{severity}-{id}: {message}&quot;" />
    <MakeDir Directories="CCPCheck"/>
    <Touch Files="CCPCheck\%(CppCheckFiles.Filename)%(CppCheckFiles.Extension).stamp" AlwaysCreate = "true" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

hmm.. this sounds interesting. I can't help you. But it would be nice if the cppcheck wiki or manual had some small example project that did this.

Some people use cppcheck in commit hooks. I've tried it with GIT myself (I added a linux shell script). And there is a TortoiseSVN plugin you can try (http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/cppcheck/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=443).